# Javadoc with Gradle : show also private members

Tags: javadoc, gradle

I am generating the Javadoc from my project with gradle, and I want to get in the Javadoc and also the private members.

In the command line, while running javadoc, you can use the -private flag to achieve that. But, how can I do that on my build.gradle?

I have my task in the next way:

```
task myJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {    
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath = configurations.compile
    destinationDir = file("./doc/")
  }
```

I am sure that there is any "option" there for doing that, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found it!

It has to be set to a [JavadocMemberLevel](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/external/javadoc/JavadocMemberLevel.html) with **options.memberLevel**.

Task should look like that:

```
task myJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {    
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PRIVATE
    classpath = configurations.compile
    destinationDir = file("./doc/")
  }
```